# Make Order notes required if shipping method is local pickup in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In Woocommerce, I would like that checkout **Order Notes field** will be "required" only when **local pickup is selected** as a shipping method.

I've managed to change the local pickup label so that the customer is instructed to add details to this field but wondered if there was a way of not allowing them to proceed until they have added details to this section?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will make **"Order notes"** as a mandatory field for **"Local Pickup"** chosen shipping method only and will display an error notice if customer try to submit his order for this requirements:

```
// Validate mandatory "Order notes" field for "Local Pickup" shipping methods
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'local_pickup_order_comment_validation', 20 );
function local_pickup_order_comment_validation() {
    // Convert the array to a comma separated string of values
    $chosen_shipping_methods =  implode( ',', WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods') );

    // Targeting any "local_pickup" shipping method
    if ( false !== strpos( $chosen_shipping_methods, 'local_pickup' ) && empty($_POST['order_comments']) ){
        wc_add_notice( __( "You need to fill up \"Order notes\" with some details.", "woocommerce" ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Related: [Make Checkout Order notes field required for shipping method ID in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76570931/make-checkout-order-notes-field-required-for-shipping-method-id-in-woocommerce/76570977#76570977)

Comment: Thanks Loic (again) for your help here. The code works but does not display the error notice, but does highlight all the existing required fields with a green border except the order comments section.

Comment: Ok, yes, I can see that it works on your test install and I've just worked out what the problem is. Thanks Loic