# Make Checkout Order notes field required for shipping method ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I am trying to make the order/shipping notes field mandatory on the checkout page, for a specific shipping method.

Following this thread: [Make Order notes required if shipping method is local pickup in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535670/make-order-notes-required-if-shipping-method-is-local-pickup-in-woocommerce/49536229#49536229), I am using below code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'danskefragtmand_order_comment_validation', 20 );
function danskefragtmand_order_comment_validation() {
    $chosen_shipping = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
    $chosen_shipping = explode(':', $chosen_shipping);
  
    if ( $chosen_shipping[0] == 'shipmondo:26' && empty($_POST['order_comments']) ){
        wc_add_notice( __( "Please tell the courier where he can leave your package in case you are not at home during time of delivery.", "woocommerce" ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

The code above works very well if I use the standard woocommerce shipping terms such as `local_pickup` and `free_shipping`, and also if u change my own term `shipmondo:26` to just `shipmondo`, but then the notice will display for all other `shipmondo` shipping methods. I am trying to target the specific ID `26`.

Any advice would be appriciated.

Other helpful thread: [Disable only specific flat rate shipping method when free shipping is available in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571655/disable-only-specific-flat-rate-shipping-method-when-free-shipping-is-available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need, in the code, to replace the line:

```
if ( $chosen_shipping[0] == 'shipmondo:26' && empty($_POST['order_comments']) ){
```

with:

```
if ( $chosen_shipping === 'shipmondo:26' && empty($_POST['order_comments']) ){
```

Now it should work.

To make the code even better, replace your code with:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'danskefragtmand_order_comment_validation', 20 );
function danskefragtmand_order_comment_validation() {
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');

    if ( in_array('shipmondo:26', $chosen_shipping_methods) && empty($_POST['order_comments']) ){
        wc_add_notice( __( "Please tell the courier where he can leave your package in case you are not at home during time of delivery.", "woocommerce" ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thank you for the the prompt reply and solution! It is working now as expected, and I now know what I did wrong. Please also accept my kind donation (paypal) on behalf of the company I work for. Wishing you a good day :)